# PHP RSS parser - - not working

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-parsing, rss

Hello I'm working on parsing this feed and cannot seem to get it to work

```
<?php
$url = "http://insite.unthsc.edu/dailynews/category/campus-news/feed/";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
print_r($xml);
?>
```

I get [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ezjm99z58gfqeu3/Screenshot%202015-12-07%2014.27.22.png?dl=0) currently when I output pre
I've done this before for other feeds and xml files but cannot for the life of me figure out why it is not working this time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is right in the error message: you need to *authenticate* before loading the XML resource.

Open [the link](http://insite.unthsc.edu/dailynews/category/campus-news/feed/) in an Incognito window, or

```
curl http://insite.unthsc.edu/dailynews/category/campus-news/feed/
```

and you'll see what PHP sees.